# Polkadot error: could not compile `zeroize` OR file too small to be an archive, could not compile `ring`

Tags: parity, polkadot

I'm going through the ["Hacking on Polkadot"](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot) section of the read me of Polkadot repo, I try to `cargo build --release` which didn't work so i tried `cargo build` here are the respective errors i got:

After `cargo build --release` i get this error:

```
error: failed to add native library /Users/Decentration/polkadot-clone/polkadot/target/release/build/ring-75cdcd2b7eadbbe2/out/libring-core.a: 

file too small to be an archive error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile ring
```

2. Instead of `cargo build --release` i tried `cargo build` then i got this error:

```
220 | pub use zeroize_derive::Zeroize;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   error: aborting due to previous error 
   error: could not compile zeroize
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: This might be an issue with LLVM [from this vaguely similar issue](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/9806) - what kind of machine are you building on? Have you updated the toolchain for rust? `rustup update` and report `rustup show` here to help

Comment: @NukeManDan You're probably right i didnt rustup update, but now i did and here it is, i am in the process of building it (thanks):


`Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/decentration/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2019-05-22-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-01-13-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-01-30-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)`

Comment: @NukeManDan unfortunately i'm still getting same errors with either  `cargo build --release`or `cargo build`. Do i need to release it with a nightly perhaps?

Comment: it also says it could not compile ring

`error: failed to add native library /Users/decentration/polkadot-clone/polkadot/target/release/build/ring-75cdcd2b7eadbbe2/out/libring-core.a: file too small to be an archive

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile ring`

I'm currently trying to release with tthe 2021-01-30 nightly, maybe

Comment: There are known issues with mac M1 ARM chips, are you using this? Unfortunately it's a pain and not advised to use these for now. If you want to try, see this: https://vikiival.medium.com/run-substrate-on-apple-m1-a2699743fae8

Comment: @NukeManDan i'm using an old macbook so its not an issue, i've also spun up multiple substrate chains node templates in the past.

Comment: Another user also shared this tip for M1 compilation:
" You need clone the rust-rocksdb repo and checkout the commit listed here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/122 then you can create a config.toml file in your .cargo folder in your home directory and add a path to that cloned repo "

Comment: sorry I missed your last comment @decentration - were you able to resolve this? with the most updtated rustc, try a `cargo clean` and cargo build --release` once more to confirm it's not a strange build artifact issue.

Comment: @NukeManDan thanks for the follow up. I spent the past week working on a substrate-node-template, today i am attempting to get hacking on a polkadot node. I will try the above then comment back here.

Comment: I'm starting to realise it may because my hard drive is too full: the build fails part of the way through; then i delete some file in my computer; come back to re-build it and then it gives me the aforementioned errors. So i am currently deleting the build/target file and starting again.

Comment: ** NOW ITS WORKING! ** @NukeManDan the cargo clean (which basically deletes the release folder) plus a computer with enough space allowed it to work. half compiled build can cause problems on recompile.

Answer (score 2):

if there is a build failed make sure you `cargo clean` before recompiling in case there are artifiacts causing problems. I recompiled successfully with `cargo build --release` then `cargo run -- --dev` afterwards.

Thanks to @NukaManDan who helped me in comments.